# Taking values from one dataframe based on time values from other

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have two pandas dataframe:

```
df1:
time                   values
2020-01-26 02:00:00    3741.54
2020-01-26 02:15:00    3741.6
2020-01-26 02:30:00    3741.66
2020-01-26 02:45:00    3741.72
2020-01-26 03:00:00    3741.8
2020-01-26 03:15:00    3741.88
2020-01-26 03:30:00    3741.99
```

```
df2
values                   time
unknown        2020-01-26 15:09:11
unknown        2020-01-26 17:14:04
47520.0        2020-01-27 01:49:01
47525.0        2020-01-27 13:56:25
47530.0        2020-01-27 15:36:42
47535.0        2020-01-28 00:08:44
47540.0        2020-01-28 00:54:16
unknown        2020-01-28 01:37:47
47540.0        2020-01-28 01:38:23
```

I want to create a final_df such that we check the time t from df1, and see the nearest row corresponding to time t in df2. if not exact then nearest past time corresponding to it. (the example dataframe provided here are not synced but i have synced dataframe at my end. the dataframe shwon here are for mere understanding the structure of the data.)

Comment: Take a look at [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html).

Comment: using merge_asof worked well. thank you @henry

Answer (score 0):

Let us try with `reindex`

```
fdf=df2.set_index('time').reindex(df1.time, method = 'nearest').reset_index()
```